# Get twitter followers who use iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

I was wondering if there is a way to get only those twitter followers who use iOS. Or alternatively get a field indicating which devices the followers use. Like in facebook we can query it for the array of user's devices using: "select devices from user where...".

Currently I am using the REST API v1.1 to get followers. But unable to determine their device OS. Is there any way to do it in twitter?

Comment: how twitter will tag a purticular device id to a user, it can be multiple

Comment: Even an array of devices would be fine if I can get them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way but each Tweet contains a "source" value which indicates what app the user used to post that Tweet.

e.g. this Tweet of mine was posted using Twitter for iPhone:
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show/299800258660151296.json?include_entities=true

The "source" value is:

```
"source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>",
```

So in your case you should first get your list of followers then get the last Tweet from each of those users and check the "source" value.

You will have to compile a list of iOS apps though to match against the source.

Also you will hit rate limits pretty quickly.

An alternative is to use the Twitter public streaming API, follow the users you want to analyse and check the source value there. You won't hit rate limits this way but it may take awhile for all the followers to Tweet.

Answer (score 1):

No, Currently Twitter is not providing any api which can give you the followers who use iOS.

You can get only followers list,but can not determine whether he/she uses iOS or not.